# Spark application to delete files after certain interval from s3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to create a spark application which deletes the files from s3 after every one hour by checking the creation time of the file
If the creation time of the file is greater than the current timestamp minus one hour than the file should be deleted
Is there a way I can achieve this

Comment: Why would you use Spark for this? I believe that setting bucket retention policy or creating Lambdas is more efficient.

Comment: bucket retention has a min interval of 24h. But I'd still do it in a single process as you don't need spark

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the s3 APIs to list all files and build up bulk DELETE requests and post them. Keep each batch to a couple of hundred, not the max 500 value, as each row is a write from your quota of a few thousands write per second (see HADOOP-16823. Large DeleteObject requests are their own Thundering Herd).

if you want to use the hadoop fs apis in java or scala

1. use FileSystem.listFiles(path, true) for an efficient deep recursive scan and incremental fetching of pages of results.
2. queue the actual delete() calls to a thread pool
3. always handy to collect and print stats on IO (number of files scanned, number deleted, mean time for a delete() to finish etc)

Example ASF licensed code to [scan a dir tree and print the status values](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/store/commands/ListFiles.java#L98). this is all you need to do, but look at the age of status entries and queue for deletion if too old